# Webdriver doesn't counts the elements on page properly (JAVA SELENIUM)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to count the elements on the page. It worked for almsot a whole year perfectly fine but now my method is always giving a wrong value so my assertion fails. It gives random numbers that dont have any logical relationship.

```
public int getCountOfResults (Webdriver webdriver) {
    try {
         waitUntilFoundByLocatorAndIsDisplayed(webDriver,By.xpath("//div[@class='hello']/div/a"));
         List <WebElement> countProduct = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='hello']/div/a"));
         return countProduct.size();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show source of page you are trying to extract data from ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. However we don't have the visibility to the method `waitUntilFoundByLocatorAndIsDisplayed()`. As a solution you can induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use the following solution:

```
public int getCountOfResults (Webdriver webdriver) {
    try {
        waitUntilFoundByLocatorAndIsDisplayed(webDriver,By.xpath("//div[@class='hello']/div/a"));
        List <WebElement> countProduct = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='hello']/div/a")));
        return countProduct.size();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```